# Is there a way to get a customized build of tinyMCE?

Tags: tinymce, wysiwyg

I had a look of the TinyMCE editor and it looks to have all cool stuffs and even the community looks a active one. But the build size is around  350kb (minified) and around 112kb (gzipped).
**I just have the requirement to include the bottom icons toolbar excluding the top menu bar**... Is there a way to get the build customized build reduced in size ????

Any suggestions would be helpful ???

Comment: It's Javascript.  You can modify it any way you want.

Comment: But the GNU license says it should be used as it is !!

Comment: Wait, what?  The GNU license is `open-source`.  The reason you're provided with the source code is so you can *modify it for your purposes.*  Read up on the license for other conditions.

Comment: Thanks Robert.. Will go through the license once again

Comment: http://www.tldrlegal.com/license/gnu-general-public-license-v3-(gpl-3)

Answer (score 1):

No, there is no way to get a customized build from Moxiecode (the developers of tinymce).
As already stated you can reduze the regular build packet to your needs by hand.
If used in a commercial application a GNU license may not be sufficient.
Contact a lawyer to make sure your are on the "right" side.